# For loop checking random values (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have to write a program that throws two die and then multiplies the results. The main goal is to find which product is the most frequent. What I need help with is writing a for-loop that checks each possible product : 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,30,36. And when it gets one of those, I want it to add 1 to a separate list, where each index is for each possible product (so 18 indeces).

I've managed to do it, but in my version, there's an if-statement for each possible result, but I need it to be shorter, because it makes the program go through too many lines, while I want it to be able to calculate a big number of die-throws without dying.

```
import random   

number_of_throws = int(input("How many times do you want to throw the die? "))

possible_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]
frequency_table = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

word = ["The products", "===========", ""]
word_2 = ["The frequency of the products", "==================================", ""]

for x in range(number_of_throws):
  dice_nr1 = random.randint(1,6)
  dice_nr2 = random.randint(1,6)
  product = dice_nr1 * dice_nr2

  if product == possible_values[0]:
    frequency_table[0] = frequency_table[0]+1
  elif product == possible_values[1]:
    frequency_table[1] = frequency_table[1]+1
  elif product == possible_values[2]:
    frequency_table[2] = frequency_table[2]+1  
  elif product == possible_values[3]:
    frequency_table[3] = frequency_table[3]+1  
  elif product == possible_values[4]:
    frequency_table[4] = frequency_table[4]+1  
  elif product == possible_values[5]:
    frequency_table[5] = frequency_table[5]+1  
  elif product == possible_values[6]:
    frequency_table[6] = frequency_table[6]+1  
  elif product == possible_values[7]:
    frequency_table[7] = frequency_table[7]+1
```

Now the elif-statements go on for like 8 more rows, but you get the point. My classmates have suggested defining a function, but I don't know how I would code it.

Comment: Btw dice is plural and die is singular, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to do this.

You might consider using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import random 
from collections import Counter 

num_throws=50

cnt=Counter()
for i in range(num_throws):
    cnt[random.randint(1,6)*random.randint(1,6)]+=1
    
print(cnt)
```

Or if you specifically want the 0 values in the result, you can use `.fromkeys` to initialize a dict and increment that 0 value:

```
import random 

cnt={}.fromkeys((i * j for i in range(1, 7) for j in range(1, 7)), 0)

num_throws=50

for i in range(num_throws):
    cnt[random.randint(1,6)*random.randint(1,6)]+=1
    
print(cnt)
```

Or just initialize the Counter with 0 value keys:

```
cnt=Counter({i * j: 0 for i in range(1, 7) for j in range(1, 7)}) # only the possible keys
```

---

If you want to print the keys by max values:

For the dict:

```
print({k:v for k,v in sorted(cnt.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))})
```

For the counter:

That is the default, but you can use `cnt.most_common(n)` for a subset.

Comment: This is what I would do as well, since the OP wanted to initialize all valid values, perhaps you might seed the counter with `cnt = collections.Counter({i * j: 0 for i in range(1, 7) for j in range(1, 7)})`

Comment: Ya, I had a bad `range()`. I updated my comment to reflect what I had intended. a counter from 1 to 36 but only valid results. For example omitting `7` as a key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm speaking off the top of my head here, but it seems that you might be able to do something like the example below.  Your example, by the way, may be a bit misleading because the first 6 lines are sequential and could lead a reader to infer that the next line is 7 rather than 8...

Anyway, for something like this I might try a dictionary rather than a list:

```
import random

number_of_throws = 1000

freq_dict = {}

for x in range(number_of_throws):
    die_nr1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die_nr2 = random.randint(1,6)
    product = die_nr1 * die_nr2

    if product not in freq_dict:
        freq_dict[product] = 1
    else:
        freq_dict[product] += 1

print(freq_dict)
```

Then you can iterate through the dictionary, with the allowable values as the key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary. You can define a list of all possible products using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`. This will produce duplicates (e.g. 2 * 6 == 3 * 4), which you can get rid of by converting the list to a set. Use that as keys, and a list of zeros as values in a set comprehension.

```
import random
import itertools

number_of_throws = int(input("How many times do you want to throw the die? "))

possible_products = [
    x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 7), 2)
]

results_dict = {
    k: v for k, v in zip(set(possible_products), [0] * len(set(possible_products)))
}

for x in range(number_of_throws):
    dice_nr1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice_nr2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    product = dice_nr1 * dice_nr2
    print(dice_nr1, dice_nr2)

    results_dict[product] += 1

for k, v in sorted(results_dict.items()):
    print(f"{k} -> {v}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with a list that you initialise to all zeroes. Do your pseudo-random calculation and update the appropriate element. Then find the index of the maximum value from the list. With a reasonably high number of iterations you would expect a result of either 6 or 12.

```
from random import randint

ITERATIONS = 100_000

result = [0] * 37

for _ in range(ITERATIONS):
    result[randint(1, 6) * randint(1, 6)] += 1

print(result.index(max(result)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try it!